# JMS ObjectMessage classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I'm trying to create a simple example with Java EE JMS.

If i try to receive an ObjectMessage, i need to have exactly the same path (packagename) as the other project, which sends the ObjectMessage.

For example i have in my sender project a class called Person in the packege "org.queue.sender" and exactly the same class in my receiver project in the package "org.queue.receiver".

As already said, if i try to get the objectmessage i get the following Exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.queue.sender.Person

If i create a new package in my receiver project named org.queue.sender and transfer the class Peron there, then it run. but i think i couldn't be the really solution.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html):

> An ObjectMessage object is used to send a message that contains a serializable object in the Java programming language ("Java object"). It inherits from the Message interface and adds a body containing a single reference to an object. Only Serializable Java objects can be used.

So, objects passed via ObjectMessages must be `Serializable` i.e. it must be the same class and the exact same package.

If you need more flexible handling of messages I suggest that you use e.g. `TextMessage` and serialize/deserialize the objects using e.g. JSON or XML.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ... ; // Get hold of a Jackson ObjectMapper
session.createTextMessage(mapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo));

// and on the receiving side
TextMessage message = ....; // From the message receiver
MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(message.getText(), MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can i have access to the original class (Person) in the sender project? So that i don't need to make a copy of the class Person?

Comment: If the class `Person` exists on *BOTH* the sender and the receiver (the exact same class with the exact same package) then you can use `ObjectMessage` and reuse the `Person`-class. Otherwise, you can not reuse and should therefor use some other type of serialization.